# getting mysql data from several unique text inputs without creating multiple connection scripts?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an HTML table which has text inputs for each row, depending on the table in question, there could be anywhere from five to five hundred unique text inputs which need to store their inputs separately, so they can be called and displayed on that same row.

With my current database connection script, and HTML set up the way it is, all the inputs will be stored in the same table with no way to differentiate between one set of data or another.

What solution to this problem would work, short of having to create a seperate and unique script for every single input?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat' + $(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});

$('.submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var me = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",     
      data: {price : me.closest('.input').val()},
      url: "link/to/your/mysql/function/"
   }).done(function(html){
      alert(success);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Destination</td>
    <td>Updated on</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>
      <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">+ On Store</button>
    </td>
    <td>22/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Amount:
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>
      <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="2">+ On Store</button>
    </td>
    <td>22/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat2" style="display:none">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Amount:
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("mysql_url","id","password");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }



mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);

 $var = $_POST[price];

$sql="INSERT INTO table (price)

VALUES

('$var')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 record added";



mysql_close($con)

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to enter new data without having to run a separate command for every single entry.

I also see you have a separate submit button for every field, which can be unwise.

You can try two things right now:

1) Make a global Submit button that counts for the entire table. You can use a `foreach()` loop in PHP to pick up the separate values and build a single SQL command like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(price) VALUES";
$ran_once = false;
foreach($_POST as $p) {
    if($ran_once) {$sql .= ", ";}
    else {$sql .= "('$p')";}
    $ran_once = true;
}
$sql .= ";";
```

2)You can use jquery to send the data dynamically for every 'submit' button you click. This can be done with the `$.post( [address], {[data]}, [success])` function.

side note: I see a lot of people still use `mysql_*` instead of `mysqli_*`. I've used both and I think `mysqli_*` is much easier then `mysql_*` (in php)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot have a global submit button, as the information in the text inputs need to be submitted independently, the users will not typically fill in more than one at a time, or more than a few per session.

Comment: @Kreation Then I suggest you do the second, using jquery .post function to submit the new values to a second php script that only processes the values into the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use inline data attributes. When you generate the page add this to every submit button:

```
data-cat="id-of-cat-goes-here"
```

This way you can keep track which button is for which category.

You can access the values with jQuery easily. The code below will give you the ID of the category that the button relates to (assuming `this` is when you click on the button).

```
$(this).data('cat');
```

More information on how to use data attributes: [MDN - data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).